# Bind event listener with flash DateChooser component

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm new to flash, and using Macromedia flash 8.

I'd like to use in-built DateChooser component in my flash project.

So How do I bind an even handler on selection of any date? let's say I want to display selected date in another dynamic text element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it:

```
var dcListener:Object = new Object();
dcListener.change = function(evt_obj:Object) {
    var thisDate:Date = evt_obj.target.selectedDate;
    trace("date selected: " +thisDate);
};

objDateChooser.addEventListener("change", dcListener);
```